# Application doesn't run after creating unity launcher with root permission

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, .desktop

I want to Run AMPPS application which is located in : `/usr/local/ampps/`

I have created it's desktop launcher which is :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/local/ampps/ampps.png
Name=AMPPS
Exec= gksudo -k -u root /usr/local/ampps/Ampps %U
Categories=Programming;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

My problem is when I click on ampps in launcher I prompted to enter root password and after that nothing happens.

I can run the application using `sudo ./Ampps` in terminal.
How Can Fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, I just needed to clarify path to the application and then change the exec command to something like below :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/local/ampps/ampps.png
Name=AMPPS
Path=/usr/local/ampps/
Exec= gksudo -k -u root ./Ampps
Categories=Programming;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

Hope solve others problem.

Answer (score 0):

gksudo deprecated!

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Ampps
Comment=Ampps LAMP Server
Icon=/home/nda/Imágenes/ampps.png
Exec=sudo -p -k -u root ./Ampps
Path=/usr/local/ampps
Actions=
Categories=Development;
StartupNotify=true
```